# Google Play Services: UserRecoverableAuthException's intent doesn't start

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services

I'm having issues with the Google Drive SDK for Android.

Everything works fine except for some devices (on which it used to be working, but now doesn't) the Intent that is returned by `UserRecoverableAuthException.getIntent()` isn't doing anything when started via `startIntent(...)`.

All I see on Logcat is:

```
03-11 08:31:19.692: INFO/ActivityManager(552): START u0 {cat=[scope:oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive,account:myemail@googlemail.com,extrashash:1088740320] flg=0x10000004 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.TokenActivity (has extras)} from pid 27644
```

That's it. Nothing happens on the device.

This is how the Intent is launched:

```
Intent intent = e.getIntent();
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
startActivity(intent);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: post your code you might be mission some permission

Comment: While not having used this particular service, I've seen other Google services get their hiccups, and erasing their local data plus a restart sometimes helped (as sad as it may sound).

Comment: a permission in the manifest?